# Screen Orientation changes to Landscape on certain Android Devices, despite specifying portrait only

Tags: android

In my app, I only have on activity: `MainActivity`. It's supposed stay locked as portrait mode, as specified in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/noPreview"
    </activity>
```

On my Samsung Galaxy S8 (Android 8.0), no matter how I rotate my phone, it stays portrait as intended. But I noticed that on a Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini (Android 4.1), it switches when tilted and the app crashes. If starting in Landscape, it crashes when switching to Portait.

Other questions on stack say to have:

```
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

In the `<activity>` element to solve this problem, but they are already declared.

What else could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the `error log` from the console. This would help a lot. Maybe this mode isn't supported from the device. The `manifest` seems fine.

So far I can only guess:

### Bug in `onCreate`

Maybe some code is executed twice because of the orientation change when starting in landscape. Maybe you specify other orientations there.

### Not supported by device (unlikely)

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#screen

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait"/>. This is purely a filtering behavior provided by Google Play (and other services that support it) and the platform itself does not control whether your app can be installed when a device supports only certain orientations.`

### Possible Solution / Workaround

In your `MainActivity` write this below `setContentView()`:

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`